# Iterating through array of hashes in rails ,SystemStackError: stack level too deep error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I need to validate phone number which is a array of hashes.I'm using phony_rails to validate phone number. for instance,

phone_number=[{"type":"international","number":"655787"},{"type":"international","number":"65578454547"}].

I need to check whether the number is a valid phone number. I tried below code. How can I do this?. what I am doing wrong?

```
validate :phone_number

  def phone_number
    phone_number.each {|phone| validates_plausible_phone phone[:number]}
  end
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I tried get request using postman. Error goes like this              
                                                                              
 app/models/user.rb:23:in `phone_number'
app/models/user.rb:23:in `phone_number'
app/models/user.rb:23:in `phone_number'
app/models/user.rb:23:in `phone_number'
app/models/user.rb:23:in `phone_number'

Comment: You need to name your validation method something other than phone_number as that is the name of your attribute

Comment: don't the  validation method name should  be the name of the attribute which needs validation  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change the name of your validation method to something else as you already have a method `phone_number` in your class. The infinite loop is expected as you are calling `phone_number` from inside of `phone_number` method.

```
validate :valid_phone_number

def valid_phone_number
  phone_number.each {|phone| validates_plausible_phone phone[:number]}
end
```

Also, it is clear that `phone_number` is an array, so please rename it to `phone_numbers` (plural).

Comment: That was the mistake and there is another mistake in the method definition. I should have used PhonyRails.plausible_number?(phone["number"])     instead of validates_plausible_phone phone[:number]